# How can I define == operator when comparing vectors of classes and objects?

Tags: c++

I want my program to stop when vector has the same colors over 3 times.
Here, I used 'if(b==all_colors[i])' but I'm getting the error.
Is this because I didn't use the template ? Do I have to rewrite the whole code?

```
#include<iostream>
#include<string>
#include<sstream>
#include<vector>

using namespace std;

class Bag
{
    string marble;

public:
    Bag(string marble)
    {
        this->marble=marble;
    }

    string add_marble()
    {
        return marble;
    }
};

class Marble_exception
{
    vector<Bag>all_colors;
    int count=0;

public:
    void add_color(Bag b)
    {
        for(int i=0; i<all_colors.size(); i++)
        {
            if(b==all_colors[i])
            {
                count++;
            }
        }

        if(count>=3)
        {
            cout<<"Sorry, you already have three of these marbles.\n\n";
        }
        else
        {
            all_colors.push_back(b);
            cout<<"added.\n\n";
        }
    }
};
```

Comment: When asking about build errors, then always include a [mcve] which we can use to replicate the errors (and only the errors you ask about). Then copy-paste (as text) the actual errors you get, in full and complete, into the question, and add comments in the code where you get the errors.

Comment: The names you choose for your classes and mathods are crazy. Take the time to decide on sensible names for the code you are writing. This will help you think clearly about the problems you are solving.

Comment: I see. I'm having difficulty asking questions in a proper way. I'll keep that in mind for later.

Answer (score 2):

No you don't have to rewrite the whole code. The error is because there is no `operator==` for your `Bag` class. C++ knows how to compare `vector<T>` but only if it also knows how to compare `T`. Add this to your code

```
class Bag
{
    ...
    // new code
    friend bool operator==(const Bad& x, const Bag& y)
    {
        return x.marble == y.marble;
    };
    // new code
};
```

This code defines `operator==` for `Bag` so now there should be no problems using `==` for `vector<Bag>`.

Answer (score 2):

C++ doesn't define automatically an `==` operator when you define a class.
There is no specific reason, but this is the situation.

If you want to be able to tell if a `Bag` is equal or not to another `Bag` you need to tell how to perform this test by defining an `bool operator==(const Bag& other) const` method in your class or a suitable free operator overload.

Note that even if you explain how to check if `a == b` for your class instances the compiler will not infer how to tell if `a != b` automatically; that is also something you need to do explicitly. Once again don't look too hard for a reason for that, it's just the way C++ currently is.

There should be a simplification for creating all comparison methods at once in C++20 with the new "spaceship" operator `<=>`.

Answer (score 2):

As others noted, the error is due to `Bag` not having an `operator==`. Others also showed how to implement one.
However, if you're using C++20, you could have the compiler implement `operator==` as well as other operators (`!=`, `<`, `<=`, `>`, `>=`) for you, which also has an advantage if you will add members to your class (unless of course you wouldn't want them to participate in the comparison - in which case you'll need to resort to implementing these operators on your own).

Here's how I'd do it in C++20:

```cpp
// Insert this inside class Bag
auto operator<=>(const Bag&) const = default;
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use from a map that  define class Bag as key to the number of colors.

```
map< Bag , int> Marble;
```

But you should define operator < for class Bag as follow :

```
bool operator <(const Bag& inBag) const
{
    return(marble.compare(inBag.marble) < 0);
}
```